# Value of $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{xa^{x}}{x!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{x=o}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{-3}3^{x}}{x!} = 3 $$

How exactly is this solved?

I know to pull out the constants to get

$$e^{-3}\sum_{x=o}^{\infty}\frac{x3^{x}}{x!}$$, but I'm unable to find a general formula for $$\sum_{x=o}^{\infty}\frac{xa^{x}}{x!}$$ how exactly do I derive one?

Comment: $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{xa^{x}}{x!}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{xa^{x}}{x!}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{x}}{(x-1)!}=\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{z+1}}{z!}=a\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{z}}{z!}=ae^a$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Recall that $$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$and that $$\frac{de^z}{dz}=e^z$$Can you take it from here?

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> We have $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$.  Then, taking a derivative, we find that $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nz^{n-1}}{n!}$.  Now, multiplying by $z$ gives $$ze^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nz^{n}}{n!}$$whereupon setting $z=3$ reveals that $$3e^3=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n3^{n}}{n!}$$Finally, multiplying both sides by $e^{-3}$, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{ne^{-3}3^{n}}{n!}=3$$and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the term with $x = 0$ first. You can just drop it out of the sum.

Next look at a term $\frac{x3^x}{x!}$ with $x > 0$. Can you cancel anything? Can you simplify so the result is still a power of 3 divided by a factorial?

Finally use $\sum_{x = 0}^\infty \frac{3^x}{x!} = e^3$.